# Return all fields from table or return that not exist in one query

Tags: mysql

I want to get all fields from row, after give `id`, but if no rows in table with specified `id` then I want to return 'not exists' or something. I need this in one query.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0afa50

Comment: Could you, please, make a sample of response you want to get?

Comment: if id is in table return *, but if not exists return one 'not exists' or 'not exists' in each column

Comment: can u explain what do u mean by : if not exists return one 'not exists' or 'not exists' in each column

Comment: Possible dublicate of [Return a default value if no rows found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15319264/4275342)

Comment: @mariusz Why do you want to solve this task in SQL? Isn't it easier to substitute default values via programming language that you use?

Comment: i need this to xml loop, I don't have permission to engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think only of this solution:

```
(SELECT * FROM `new_table` WHERE id = 1)
UNION 
(SELECT 'not exists!' AS id, 'not exists!' AS name, 'not exists!' AS surname, 'not exists!' AS anotherfield 
 FROM new_table 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `new_table` WHERE id = 1)
);
+----+------+---------+--------------+
| id | name | surname | anotherfield |
+----+------+---------+--------------+
| 1  | aaa  | ssss    | adad         |
+----+------+---------+--------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

(SELECT * FROM `new_table` WHERE id = 0) 
UNION 
(SELECT 'not exists!' AS id, 'not exists!' AS name, 'not exists!' AS surname, 'not exists!' AS anotherfield         
 FROM new_table         
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `new_table` WHERE id = 0)        
);
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| id          | name        | surname     | anotherfield |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| not exists! | not exists! | not exists! | not exists!  |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

UPDATE: It's quite ugly as you see. Why do you need to solve this task via SQL? Isn't it easier to substitute default values in programming language that you use (I hope)?

Comment: ...simpler / less ugly query omitting WHERE NOT EXISTS and uses LIMIT 1 @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319264/return-a-default-value-if-no-rows-found/34758622#34758622  As for why to do this via SQL, for my OOP project use, I am iterating the result object and building table structure from it (column headings and values).  By ensuring non-erring queries have 1 row, I don't have to recode the table structure.