# convert the following php to SQL only

Tags: php, sql

```
function fetch_Actor($ActorID){
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM actors WHERE ActorID = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$ActorID]);
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
$actors = fetch_actor($actor['ActorID']);   
foreach ($actors as $actor){
    if($actor['ParentID'] > 0){
    $actor = fetch_actor($actor['ParentID']);
    }
}
```

The code above is something I wrote to override duplicate actors in my database. I believe what I am trying to do in php can be done with one statement in SQL. I just do not know where to begin. I am looking for some guidance on how to do this in one sql statement and get rid of my unnecessary `foreach()` loop to fix stuff.

I am trying to include in my sql statment this condition:

- if ParentID > 0 then fetch results using ParentID
- else fetch results using ActorID

Table Structure

```
Actors 
ActorID    |    Name    | ParentID
      1    |    Abel    | 0
      2    |    John    | NULL
      3    |    Abel    | 1
```

What I want to be returned if $ActorID = 1

```
Actors 
ActorID    |    Name    | ParentID
      1    |    Abel    | 0
```

What I want to be returned if $ActorID = 2

```
Actors 
ActorID    |    Name    | ParentID
      2    |    John    | NULL
```

What I want to be returned if $ActorID = 3

```
Actors 
ActorID    |    Name    | ParentID
      1    |    Abel    | 0
```

I have tried this, but this does not seem to work:

```
IF((SELECT ParentID FROM actors WHERE ActorID = ?) > 0) 
 SELECT * FROM actors WHERE ParentID = ? 
ELSE 
 SELECT ParentID FROM actors WHERE ActorID = ?
```

Comment: We can't see your table structure/data.  Do you just want to establish a backup value (or default) if one is missing?  How about something like this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34758622/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa fixed.

Comment: What if there is a long chain of parents, should we follow it?
Something like: 4 Abel 3 ? From the code at the top it looks like answer is yes.

Comment: @Elhana I made sure that the parent stays a parent. my scenario has only child and parent.

Comment: @shnisaka please disambiguate your table data, so that your question is clear about `Name` when `ActorID` equals `1` and `3`.  (just give `ActorID` `3` a different `Name` value)  If you found my linked answer "helpful" you probably know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way without the UNION - LIMIT technique:

```
SELECT * FROM actors WHERE (actorid=? AND parentid<1) OR actorid=(SELECT parentid FROM actors WHERE actorid=?)
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c79a8/7)

This assumes there is no need to use LIMIT because there can logically only be one row in the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not ideal, but should work:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM actors a 
inner join (SELECT ParentID,ActorID FROM actors WHERE ActorID = ?) q 
on (((q.ParentID = 0 or q.ParentID is Null) and a.ActorID = q.ActorID) 
OR (q.ParentID > 0 and a.ActorID = q.ParentID))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5a228/7

p.s. unlike the code it is not recursive, but accorsing to comments it is not required.

Comment: Your code works thanks! I found an easier solution though =)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if mysql has something like oracles CONNECT BY. Whatever works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The UNION statement probably works best for this as suggested by @mickmackusa:

```
SELECT * FROM Actors WHERE ActorID = 1 AND (ParentID = 0 OR ParentID IS NULL)
 UNION 
SELECT * FROM Actors WHERE ActorID = (SELECT ParentID FROM Actors WHERE ActorID = 1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5a228/10/0