# What does the 2 in the MySqli select statement represent?

Tags: mysql

What does

```
SELECt 2 type, c.*, p.name 
FROM customer c 
LEFT JOIN product p ON (c.id = p.cid) WHERE c.id='5' 
GROUP BY p.name
```

return?

What does the 2 in the statement represent

Comment: is literal  value.. the query show 2 as result for the first column ... named  with  alias type

Comment: this is to return a fixed value as `type` column, more about that in [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/literals.html), this is called literal values as @scaisEdge had mentioned

Comment: I always use the optional keyword AS for readability. "SELECT 2 AS type" looks way better

Comment: Thank you guys, so another question, In what cases would one want to add an extra column with a value 2?

Comment: This can streamline the outputting process by delivering all data from a single source  (`$resultset`) rather than some from here and some from there.  You can just loop the resultset.  Here is one use case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34758622/2943403 that makes the resultset handling simpler.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or PHP's mysqli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just adds an additional column to the result set before other columns. The value of this column is always 2. And a `type` alias is given to it.