# How to get and AVG if records are present or else return some default value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables Catalogue and Reviews. Their structure looks likes :

```
Catalogue Table

  PId | PName | PImg | Price | 
------|------------------------
 1    |  AB   |  x.v |   1
 2    |  CD   |  y.v |   2
```

and

```
Review Table

  ID  | UserID | PId | Review | 
------|------------------------
 1    |    1   |  1  |   5
 2    |    2   |  1  |   4
```

PId in the review table is a foreign key to the Catalogue table. What I am trying to do is to fetch all the records of `Catalouge` and Average of Review from the `Review` Table.

I have tried `LEFT JOIN`like

```
SELECT Catalogue.*, AVG(Reviews.Review) AS AvgReview 
  FROM Catalogue 
  LEFT JOIN Reviews ON Catalogue.PId = Reviews.ProdID
```

but this only return the 1 row with average of 4.5, while the row with PId = 2 is not returned. How can I get both the rows from `Catalogue` table and their corresponding reviews from `Review` table if present or else return some default value? Row with PId = 2 is not returned cause no reviews in `Review` table is found with PId = 2, so i want to replace and return the row with some default value.

The question sounds simple but I am beginner, any help will be appreciated. Thank you.
Also i have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319264/return-a-default-value-if-no-rows-found/34758622) and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74192/select-first-value-if-exists-otherwise-select-default-value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` the columns of the catalog table.

```
SELECT c.pid,
       c.pname,
       c.pimg,
       c.price,
       avg(r.review) avg_review
       FROM catalogue c
            LEFT JOIN reviews r
                      ON r.pid = c.pid
       GROUP BY c.pid,
                c.pname,
                c.pimg,
                c.price;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select column1, column2, avg(column3) from table1 ...
```

will return column1, column2 from any row matching the join or other condition you specify.

You need to specifically pickup...